# jq: aggregate cost in nested json

Tags: json, jq

I have following json:

```
 [
  {
  "account": "1",
  "cost": [
      {
         "usage":"low",
         "totalcost": "2.01"
      }
   ]
  },
  {
  "account": "2",
  "cost": [
      {
         "usage":"low",
         "totalcost": "2.25"
      }
   ]
  },
  {
  "account": "1",
  "cost": [
      {
         "usage":"low",
         "totalcost": "15"
      }
   ]
  },
  {
  "anotheraccount": "a",
  "cost": [
      {
         "usage":"low",
         "totalcost": "2"
      }
   ]
  }
]
```

I run following command on it:

```
jq '.[] | {account,cost : .cost[].totalcost}'
```

which gives me:

```
  {
  "account": "1",
  "cost": "2.01"
   }
  {
  "account": “2”,
  "cost": “2.25”
   }
   {
  "account": “1”,
  "cost": “15”
   }
```

Then I try to pipe to aggregate values, but getting wrong results:

```
jq '.[] | {account,cost : .cost[].totalcost}'  | jq -n 'reduce (inputs | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({}; .[$key] += $value)'
```

getting:

```
{
    “account”: “121”
    “cost”: 19.26
}
```

but I am trying to achieve following output:

```
{
    “account”: “1”
    “cost”: “17.01”
}
{
    “account”: “2”
    “cost”: “2.25”
}
```

I am new to jq. jq is not a necessity to use in this, in anyway I can aggregate the values will work for me.

Comment: You're at least missing a `group_by` to tell jq not to sum every cost together but every cost for a same account together

Comment: @Aaron - tried this: jq '.[] | {account,cost : .cost[].totalcost}' | jq -n 'group_by(.[account]) | jq -n 'reduce (inputs | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({}; .[$key] += $value)' .. But getting error

Comment: @oguzismail - I think it works but returns account as 1 only for all.

Comment: Meh, I was in the process of redacting an answer when it got closed ; [this](https://jqplay.org/s/owhGJd02L1) seems to work (floating-point arithmetics aside).

Comment: @Aaron weird still erring out on my data - Cannot iterate over null (null)

Comment: I've copy-pasted the data you posted in your question, if you're working on something else I can't help you without knowing what it is. With the data you posted there was a `null` because of the last item which has no `account` field, only a `anotheraccount`, is that normal?

Comment: @Aaron - It should have both but account will be empty string in that case. Only one or other will have value.